# How to copy the href link of an anchor to other anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am showing a set of products via shortcode in WordPress. The display has an image and button.

**Problem**: Only the photo contains the link to single product page. The associated button does not have the link to the single product page.

This is the current code:

```
<div class="display-products">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="displayProduct-shortcode displayProduct-Container">
            <div class="product_grid dp-section dp-group woocommerce" id="displayProduct">
                <div class="dp_product_item dp-col dp-col_1_of_6 firstcol">
                    <div class="dp_images">
                        <a class="dp-product-image" title="Custom Made Wedding Cabinet" href="yahoo.com">
                            <div class="he-wrap tpl1">
                                <div class="dp-img-wrapper"> <img width="192" height="264" alt="#" class="attachment-display_product_thumbnail size-display_product_thumbnail wp-post-image" src="img_src"> </div>
                            </div> <span data-id="696" class="dpquickview dp_quickview_button"><img src="img_src"></span> </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dp-product-information clearfix">
                        <h2 class="product-name">
                                <a title="Custom Made Wedding Cabinet" href="#">Custom Made Wedding Cabinet</a>

                            </h2>
                        <div class="dp-stock"></div>
                        <div class="dp-grid-button"> <a class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt db_customButton" href="#">READ MORE</a> </div>
                        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Desired Output: I want to somehow iterate over each **.single_add_to_cart_button** and copy the link of every product-name to each **READ MORE** button

This is my current jquery code:

```
j('.display-products .displayProduct-shortcode .dp-product-information .dp-grid-button .single_add_to_cart_button').each(function() {
    var getProductLink = j('.display-products .displayProduct-shortcode .dp-product-information .product-name > a').attr('href');
    j(this).attr('href', getProductLink);
});
```

Comment: @satpal's answer is correct and I was about to post the same one, but I wonder why you don't just render the link in your Wordpress view in PHP instead of doing this.

Comment: Hi Growiel, I already marked Satpa's answer. He is a guru. " I wonder why you don't just render the link in your Wordpress view in PHP instead of doing this" It can't be set in PHP because it is generated by a plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `href` attribute value using the elements context. Use `closest()` to traverse up to `dp-product-information` element then find the desired `anchor` element the read its attribute and set the value.

*Use*

```
j('.display-products .displayProduct-shortcode .dp-product-information .dp-grid-button .single_add_to_cart_button').attr('href', function(){
    return j(this).closest('.dp-product-information').find('.product-name>a').attr('href');
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.dp-product-information .dp-grid-button .single_add_to_cart_button').attr('href', function() {
    return $(this).closest('.dp-product-information').find('.product-name > a').attr('href');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dp-product-information clearfix">
  <h2 class="product-name">
                            <a title="Custom Made Wedding Cabinet" href="#Test">Custom Made Wedding Cabinet</a>

                        </h2>

  <div class="dp-stock"></div>
  <div class="dp-grid-button">
    <a class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt db_customButton" href="#">READ MORE</a>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Satpal. You're a guru. Thank you. You're answer is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning value for the different buttons with the links I would like to suggest you to use a common class (if you can) then trigger the click event for them:

```
$('.selector').on('click',function(){
   $('.a-selector').trigger('click');
});
```